# Python: base64.b64decode() vs .decode?

Tags: python, base64, bind, x509certificate

The Code Furies have turned their baleful glares upon me, and it's fallen to me to implement "Secure Transport" as defined by [The Direct Project](http://wiki.directproject.org/). Whether or not we internally use DNS rather than LDAP for sharing certificates, I'm obviously going to need to set up the former to test against, and that's what's got me stuck. Apparently, an X509 cert needs some massaging to be used in a CERT record, and I'm trying to work out how that's done.

The clearest thing I've found is a script on [Videntity's blog](http://www.videntity.com/2013/08/how-to-serve-public-certificates-in-bind-for-the-direct-project/), but not being versed in python, I'm hitting a stumbling block. Specifically, this line crashes:

```
decoded_clean_pk = clean_pk.decode('base64', strict)
```

since it doesn't seem to like (or rather, to know) whatever 'strict' is supposed to represent. I'm making the semi-educated guess that the line is supposed to decode the base64 data, but I learned from the Debian OpenSSL debacle some years back that blindly diddling with crypto-related code is a Bad Thing(TM).

So I turn the illustrious python wonks on SO to ask if that line might be replaced by this one (with the appropriate import added):

```
decoded_clean_pk = base64.b64decode(clean_pk)
```

The script runs after that change, and produces correct-looking output, but I've got enough instinct to know that I can't necessarily trust my instincts here. :)

Comment: I updated the answer with the *final example!* ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line should've work if you would've called like this:

```
decoded_clean_pk = clean_pk.decode('base64', 'strict')
```

Notice that `strict` has to be a `string`, otherwise python interpreter would try to search for a variable named `strict` and if it didn't find it or otherwise has other value than: `strict`, `ignore`, and `replace`, it'll probably would've complain about it.

Take a look at this code:

```
>>>b=base64.b64encode('hello world')
>>>b.decode('base64')
'hello world'

>>>base64.b64decode(b)
'hello world'
```

Both `decode` and `b64decode` works the same when `.decode` is passed the `base64` argument string.

The difference is that `str.decode` will take a string of bytes as arguments and will return it's Unicode representation depending on the `encoding` argument you pass as first parameter. In this case, you're telling it to handle a `bas64` string so it will do it ok.

To answer your question, both works the same, although `b64decode/encode` are meant to work only with base64 encodings and `str.decode` can handle as many encodings as the library is aware of.

For further information take a read at both of the doc sections: [`decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) and [`b64decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode).

**UPDATE:** Actually, and this is the most important example I guess :) take a look at the source code for `encodings/base64_codec.py` which is that `decode()` uses:

```
def base64_decode(input,errors='strict'):

    """ Decodes the object input and returns a tuple (output
        object, length consumed).

        input must be an object which provides the bf_getreadbuf
        buffer slot. Python strings, buffer objects and memory
        mapped files are examples of objects providing this slot.

        errors defines the error handling to apply. It defaults to
        'strict' handling which is the only currently supported
        error handling for this codec.

    """
    assert errors == 'strict'
    output = base64.decodestring(input)
    return (output, len(input))
```

As you may see, it actually uses `base64` module to do it :)

Hope this clarify in some way your question.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help. One of these days, I'll have to learn python's way of doing things. :)